# My emulator doesn't work

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I just made a Hello work, and he stay like this forever.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/ni7HwbO.png]

And here what appears:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/rbHiq5t.png]

Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: If it doesn't load, delete the emulator and create a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to wait for it to load, first time it takes time to load.

you can do following things

1. Plug in the charger
2. Go to SDK Manager and download extensions about Emulator, and it should work